# Difference between v-bind and {{}}?

Tags: vue.js

I have an input field with the value field being passed a string stored in Vuex.
The input fields changes are debounced and the new string synced to Vuex.

When bound like this `:value="vuexState.myString`, when typing, the cursor jumps to the end of the line.

When bound like this `value={{vuexState.myString}}`, the cursor stays where it is.

According to the guide: http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Arguments
These two should be the same, with the `{{ }}` style being internally converted to `:bind`. Could this be a bug?

My theory is that the cursor jumping occurs because the vuex state change re-renders the input and that the `{{ }}` style is interpolated only once while the binding syntax re-renders the input every change.

I am currently using `value={{vuexState.myString}}` but I'd like to know what is happening or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried to ask your question here https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues?

Comment: that thread is a litle deprecated, use the [forum](http://forum.vuejs.org/) instead

Comment: I wouldn't have expected to see a difference here.  Can you provide code or a fiddle so we can test?

Comment: Well, have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/9q6r19eq/ looks like Vue just doesn't care about {{ }} in props

Answer (score 9):

It's in the documentation about [Interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions) and has been deprecated (see. [Migration guit from 1.x](https://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-deprecated))

#### Deprecated

This is the old way

```
<div class="btn btn-primary hint--top {{class}}"></div>
```

#### Solution

Use Javascript expression instead:

```
<div v-bind:class="'btn btn-success hint--top '+ class "></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the console, it seems like it has been deprecated in favour of the colon syntax or `v-bind`:

```
vue.js:2237 [Vue warn]: foo="{{foo}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been deprecated. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v-text:'something' === {{something}}
```