# Set value from Vue component to template

Tags: vue.js, toggle

thanks for reading my question.

I have a code like this:

```
Vue.component('list-products', {
delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
template: '#list-products-template',
props: ['products'],
data: function () {
    return {
        compareLimit: 3
    }
},
...
...


<script type="text/x-template" id="list-products-template">
<div>
    Limit  is [[ compareLimit ]]
    <div id="compare" data-toggler=".small-up-[[ compareLimit ]]" class="row small-up-1">
        ...
        ...
```

I'm trying to set "small-up" string with dynamic variable that comes from Vue but i got this error:

**Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead**

Do u know how i can pass the compareLimit variable to data-toggler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362812/difference-between-v-bind-and

Comment: You can do it like this `:data-toggler="'.small-up-' + compareLimit"`
Btw it's answered many times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between v-bind and {{}}?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362812/difference-between-v-bind-and)

Comment: Thanks for ur answers guys. @BelminBedak i apreciate ur help. Ur answer is more clear for me. What is the correct way to accept the answer? accept the answer as duplicate how says Roy or accepts yours? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sommer I won't post it as answer because It's duplicate and already answered thing.You could give vote up to answer in linked answer, because I guess this one would be closed.